# Manually create an HtmlResponse for an entity view

Tags: 9

How do I manually create an HtmlResponse object that returns the full html for an entity view; identical to the html returned for the entity.{{whatever entity id}}.canonical route?

Context: I'm subscribing "kernel.request" to check for certain URL's that are supposed to bypass Drupal Path processing altogether. For some of these I'm returning a TrustedRedirectResponse, but others should show (not redirect to) an entity view.

Comment: You could create the HtmlResponse object in a sub-request similar to Drupal creating the response of an error page set to a node. But it's unclear why you can't make an entity route match the path and let the current request build the response. The error page is built in a sub-request because the current request has failed. You don't have this problem.

Comment: @4uk4 : I've chosen to go this route (ha!) because I need to allow for any arbitrary URL to be entered by the user, and my site uses language prefixes that I need to be able to ignore. I'm not sure how else I could accomplish this. The redirect modules uses the same approach (but only redirects, obviously)

A sub request seems heavyhanded, but should work.

Comment: You could ignore the language prefix and translate the arbitrary URL to the internal entity path in a path processor with a high priority.

Comment: @4uk4 : true, I could do that, and it might work. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @4uk4: and it does work. Thanks!